# OpenGL - Disable Anti Alias

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

I can't find anything on how to hint to the driver to disable any antialias.
I'm using a very minimal passthrough setup yet I notice my driver is still doing what looks like MSAA.
I want to disable this, or at least give a strong hint to disable it, so to save performance. As I will be doing deferred rendering with my own SSAA.

Comment: OpenGL does no Anti Aliasing by itself. What you are looking at might be linear texture filtering.

Comment: To better clarify what you need, please add a screenshot.

Comment: @Mr.Beast: What makes you think texture filtering is related? Question is clearly about disabling AA.

Comment: There is no way (AFAIK) to override the driver settings, since you are already overriding your application's settings using the driver, can't go both ways.

Comment: @KromStern Linear filtering makes the textures blurry, which can be misunderstood as anti aliasing, but I agree a Screenshot is needed.

Comment: What makes you think it's doing MSAA? If I understand correctly, you're rendering a single quad to the default framebuffer. MSAA shouldn't make any visible difference to that (something like FXAA would), or have much of a performance hit.

Comment: I just remembered I had AA settings forced on for java because of minecraft. Now that I changed it its not coming back on for some reason. But thats aside from the point.
@KromStern pretty much answered it "OpenGL drivers allow user to force enable AA. I'd like to see a workaround of that too, but I'm afraid there's none."

Comment: So I guess its up to the enduser to be aware of their driver settings, and as a developer you just have to inform them of optimal settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL drivers allow user to force enable AA. I'd like to see a workaround of that too, but I'm afraid there's none.

Possible solution would be to render to a texture through FBO (which is not controlled by drivers AA setting?) and then render that texture pixely-perfect to screen.